# Access CloudFormation template in S3 from within Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I want to use `cfn_client.update_stack()` in my lambda. Here for I have to access a CF template in my S3 bucket. The IAM role attached to the lambda is correct.
I tried:

```
TemplateURL='s3://xxx/yyy/temp.yaml',
```

But it wasn't working. The template is private so I cant use the `Https://` url I assume?

How can I access the template or am I forced to download the template from the bucket inside the `/tmp` of my lambda and run it with `template-body`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aws cloudformation update-stack accepts "https".
(at least from AWS boto3 documents),
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/update-stack.html#examples

I think in your case, you'll have to either give access to the lambda via https, or just download the template and use --template-body